# Web internationalization

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, multilingual, ngx-translate

I am a beginner in the use of angular and I am very pleased with the numerous possibilities offered by this framework. However some library are pretty hard to use like the ngx-Translate.

The situation :

I start with a creative template which use an intermediate layer (admin-layout.component.html) between app-component and others :
[Fils description][1]

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div class="main-panel">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <app-select-language></app-select-language>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to set an internalization of my webapp. I already succed with the use of the browserlang (english or french) when the app is intially loaded

Now, I'm trying make functional my select-language component which aims to switch whole app language with a user selection :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-language',
  template: `
    <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
      <option
        *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()"
        [value]="lang"
        [attr.selected]="lang === translate.currentLang ? '' : null"
      >{{lang}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
})
export class SelectLanguageComponent {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {}
}
```

When a selection is made, the app-module is reach and the lang parameter transmited but I can't find a way to realoded the page in the other language...

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
// import {MultiTranslateHttpLoader} from 'ngx-translate-multi-http-loader';


import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from "./layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component";
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './layouts/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';

import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { ComponentsModule } from "./components/components.module";

NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot()
  ]
})


export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);

  //return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient,
  //environment.feServerUrl + '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export function translateFactory(translate: TranslateService) {
  return async () => {
    translate.getBrowserLang();
    // selection de la langue du navigateur :
    const langue = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.setDefaultLang(langue);
    translate.use(langue);
    translate.addLangs(['fr', 'en']);

    const supportedLangs = ["en", "fr"];
    supportedLangs.forEach((language) => {
      translate.reloadLang(language);
    });

    return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
      translate.onLangChange.subscribe((lang) => {
        this.useDefaultLang == false;
        // Called by the select-language.component
        this.currentLang = lang.lang;
        console.log("this.currentLang", this.currentLang);
        // translate.setTranslation(lang.lang, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
        // translate.setDefaultLang(this.currentLang);
        // translate.reloadLang(this.currentLang);
        translate.use(this.currentLang);
        resolve(this.currentLang);
      });
    });
  };
}




@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, AdminLayoutComponent, AuthLayoutComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: translateFactory,
      deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

All the commented code are function that dosen't work !

I thank you in advance for the help you could give.

@+

Answer (score 0):

You have only 2 ways:

1. i18n (doesn't work live reload data) - you must have subdomain or routing like:

   ```
   domain.com/en/...
   domain.com/fr/...
   ```

   or similar subdomains
2. `ngx-translate` - when you press some button - all data is redrawn without reloading page

Answer (score 0):

When using ngx-translate and a language is changed it will automatically reload all text for the current language but of course this need to be defined by you:

For example **app.component.html**:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ 'demo.title' | translate }}</h1>
</div>
```

This is 1 of 3 choices you have to do internationalization with ngx-translate.

So with that in mind:

1. create il8n folder in your assets folder

- this is where you store translations
  2)create en.json, fr.json, ando so on....

example:

en.json:

```
{
  "demo.title": "Translation demo",
  "demo.text": "This is a simple demonstration app for ngx-translate"
}
```

fr.json:

```
{
  "demo.title": "Démo de traduction",
  "demo.text": "Ceci est une application de démonstration simple pour ngx-translate"
}
```

Note: for this, I recommend you use somehting like BabelEdit so you can translate file faster and easier.... but is is a personal choice....

Based and you posted code this should work.....

Also please take a read on this

https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate

Hope this help.... in case you need more detailed explanation let me know.. I can prepare a small demo for you..

Cheers!